# Change power plan in Windows after power failure (on notebook)

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-8.1, battery, power-management

I have Windows 8.1 and would like to have my notebook automatically change the power plan to a different one when loss of AC is detected.

How can I do this?

Reason is because I have a pretty power hungry plan - no standby, etc... I put it manually to sleep when I'm finished working. But during power failure, my notebook (Dell 17" monster) won't last very long even with mobile power plans set.. but it will last much longer that way than without, which is why I want to have this auto-switch plans behaviour.

Comment: Power plans allow you to set settings for "Plugged in" and "On Battery".  Are these not working for you?

Comment: ah I forgot that was possible.. it's been a long day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you are running your laptop on AC power.  During a power loss, your laptop will be running on battery power.

To accomplish your goal, go into Windows 8.1 power settings (Power Options in the Control Panel), and set your desired power settings for **"On Battery"** and **"Plugged In"**.

This will take care of it for you!  Good luck!